# Unable to mount EBS volume on Ubuntu EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I cant seem to figure out how to mount an EBS volume to a Ubuntu EC2 instance using [Amazon's instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html). Can someone help me out?

```
~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  16G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  16G  0 part /

~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  340K   99M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       16G  7.2G  7.8G  48% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

~$ sudo file -s /dev/xvda
/dev/xvda: x86 boot sector

~$ sudo file -s /dev/xvda1
/dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=da85f42e-5e55-40d1-95da-dea139db0d7f, volume name "cloudimg-rootfs" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)

~$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvda
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/xvda is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

~$ sudo mkdir /data

~$ sudo mount /dev/xvda /data
mount: /dev/xvda already mounted or /data busy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have one disk `xvda` with one partition `xvda1`. The partition `/dev/xvda1` is already mounted at `/`. Since you only have one disk, with one partition, that is mounted as the root volume, there really isn't anything else you can do at this point. Are you trying to add a second EBS volume to your EC2 instance? If so you need to attach it to the instance first, and then look for it to show up in the `lsblk` output.

Comment: Ah, okay -- that makes sense, @mark-b. I'm new to EC2/EBS so I was a bit lost reading Amazon's instructions. As I understand, one of the benefits of using EBS is that I don't lose data if I need to change instance type, but I don't understand what directory will be saved to EBS since it's a partition. I have data stored in /home/ubuntu/. Will that datanbe saved if I change instance type?

Comment: What is the current instance type?

Answer (score 0):

here's a script for Amazon Linux 2 you can recreate for Ubuntu just try while commenting raws with yum:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y upgrade

# Format and mount an attached volume
DEVICE=/dev/$(lsblk -rno NAME | awk 'FNR == 3 {print}')
MOUNT_POINT=/data/
mkdir $MOUNT_POINT
yum -y install xfsprogs
mkfs -t xfs $DEVICE
mount $DEVICE $MOUNT_POINT

# Automatically mount an attached volume after reboot / For the current task it's not obligatory
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
UUID=$(blkid | grep $DEVICE | awk -F '\"' '{print $2}')
echo -e "UUID=$UUID     $MOUNT_POINT      xfs    defaults,nofail   0   2" >> /etc/fstab
umount /data
mount -a

# Change user for data operations / Non mandatory
chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user $MOUNT_POINT
```

from [here](https://github.com/abdibus/Terraform-Cheatsheet/tree/master/AWS-EBS-Attach-Mount)